# Unable to get list of updates in software centre

Tags: updates, software-center

Whenever I open updates section in ubuntu store, It always shows "sofrware is up to date". And when I refresh the page, it throws an error

unable to get list of updates- /usr/share/appdata no such file or directory

Can anybody find a solution? Thanks!

here is what the result is

[image]

Comment: Please add output of `ls -ald /usr/share/appdata` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1264429/edit). Do you have updates list when run `sudo apt update` followed by `apt list --upgradable` ?

Comment: I've ran these three commands. I got update list. Now when I refresh the updates section, it shows no error but still shows software is up to date even some apps have new updates